# How to pass the value from one javascript function to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass the value from one function to another onclick

```
function getReporteeList() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost:8088/JirasTrackingApp/reporter/Reportees/ReporteeList/'+ $("#ManagerId").val(),
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){      
            alert(result);  
            var content = '';
            $.each(result,function(key,value){
                content += '<tr>';
                content += '<td>'+value.Name+'</td>';
                content += '<td>'+value.UserId+'</td>';
                content += '<td>'+'<a href="#" onclick ="getJira('+value.UserId+')">'+value.count+'</a>'+'</td>';
                content += '</tr>';

            });
            $('#employee_table').append(content);
            console.log(result);


        }
    });
}
function getJira(value)
{
    var empid = document.getElementById("value").value;
    console.log(empid);
}
```

It is throwing an error on click the UserId hyperlink as:
Uncaught ReferenceError: 
at12345 is not defined
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Answer (score 1):

`value.userid` is a string, so you need quotes around it in the argument to `getJira()`.

```
content += '<td>'+'<a href="#" onclick ="getJira(\''+value.UserId+'\')">'+value.count+'</a>'+'</td>';
```

Comment: Thanks.Where should we exactly declare our function getJira because it is throwing me an error as Uncaught ReferenceError: getJira is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: It should be declared at the top level in a `<script>` tag just as you show in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event listener for your `<td>` and get the value there. Also, there are btter options than an anchor element if you are just trying to call a function.

The below solution uses just plain old javascript (no jquery). Basically it finds all spans inside of the table employeeTable. It then adds a click listener and pulls the id out. You can set value how you are currently setting everything else. You can pull out a value, a class really anything you want that contains your value.

Example:

```js
var spans = document.getElementById('employeeTable').querySelectorAll('span');
spans.forEach(function(elem){
    elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(this.id);
  }, false);
})
```

```html
<table id="employeeTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Class</td>
          <td>Link</td>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Juice</td>
            <td>Math</td>
            <td><span id="t12345">here is the click</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eggs</td>
            <td>English</td>
            <td><span id="t8675309">here is the click</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<Br><br><br>
<span>I'm a span outside of the table, I won't fire click listener</span>
```